# dupecatcher - Duplicate error from salesforce when updating Account which has same name

Tags: apex, trigger, field-update, update

I am trying to update on Account Object's one custom field by using trigger. But always hitting the below error if Similar Account Name are existed in DB.

It is so confusing and shouldn't check for duplicate based on Account Name only.

All I am doing is to update the custom field based on Id of Account. There is no place that I am trying to update the Account Name too.

Any input will be so helpful.

```
Apex script unhandled trigger exception by user/organization: xxx/xxx
Source organization: xxx (null)
Trigger_Updatexxx: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id xxx; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, <script src="/js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = SFSSDupeCatcher_doWork;

function SFSSDupeCatcher_doBlockedDuplicate() {var issueTime = '1392884311921'; var sessionId = '00DO0000004xEw8!ARwAQJYbs1QieaRstAnZIqay7k3HZe4.pPotqoQ6y33LIZs4Pa7EAwuubd.z5l9LzkwXMXNELv5iHsgcyanFMGD_SIL5u8Vc'; var scenarioId = 'a0n100000010XrxAAE'; try{SFSSDupeCatcher_incrementCounter(scenarioId, sessionId, issueTime)}catch(err){};}


function SFSSDupeCatcher_doWork() { 

  SFSSDupeCatcher_doBlockedDuplicate();

}

function SFSSDupeCatcher_incrementCounter(scenarioId, sessionId, issueTime) {var scenarioQuery = 'Select Name, Id, SFSSDupeCatcher__Blocked_Duplicates__c from SFSSDupeCatcher__Scenario__c where (Id = \'' + scenarioId + '\')'; var state = {output : 'hello', startTime : new Date().getTime() }; var callback = { onSuccess: SFSSDupeCatcher_handleResults,onFailure: SFSSDupeCatcher_queryFailed,timeout:  1200,source: state}; sforce.connection.sessionId = sessionId; sforce.connection.clientId = 'SymphonicSource/DupeCatcher/'; sforce.connection.query(  scenarioQuery , callback); } function SFSSDupeCatcher_handleResults(queryResult, source) { var records = queryResult.getArray('records'); for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) { var thisscenario = records[i]; thisscenario.SFSSDupeCatcher__Blocked_Duplicates__c++; records = sforce.connection.update(records);   }  } function SFSSDupeCatcher_queryFailed(error, source) {  } </script><font color="blue"><br/>DUPECATCHER WARNING!   The Account that you edited was not saved.</font><br/><font color="blue">It has been blocked because the value of the  Account 'Company Name' field that you entered is similar to  the 'Company Name' field of the Accounts listed below.</font><br/><br/><font color="green">Click on the links below to view or edit the potential duplicate records.</font><br/>Potential duplicate Account record: <a href="../xxxxx">Test Company</a><br/>: []
```

Comment: Which field are you modifying?
Is that field unique or external ID? 
Has that other record the same value of that field?

Comment: the custom field of Account Obj using the trigger. It has totally different value from Name of Account Obj.

Answer (score 1):

This issue may have to do with your DupeCatcher filter settings.  DupeCatcher scans for duplicates when you insert new records OR when you update existing records.  If you have a DupeCatcher account filter set to block an UPDATE, and you are updating records for which there are duplicates in the org, DupeCatcher will block the update.

This is typically an issue in orgs where there are a lot of existing duplicate records.  In this case, I recommend you set your Match on Update action on your DupeCatcher filters to Do Nothing.

You should also consider cleansing the org with an application like Cloudingo.

Best,
Steve
Symphonic Source, makers of DupeCatcher
support@symphonicsource.com

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the answer. One question, how can I access the DupeCacher Filter settings from Apex and set it Do Nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Inside of Salesforce, you will want to access the DupeCatcher app and tabs.  Either select DupeCatcher from the main Salesforce menu (upper right, blue oval around the menu title), or access the full tabs page.  Select the DupeCatcher Filters tab.  Then edit the filters matching actions--that is, change the Match on Update action to Do Nothing and Save.

Best,
Steve